# Building an object from array in javascript

Tags: javascript

What I have is an array like this: `['foo','bar']` and I want to turn it into an object that looks like this:

```
{
     foo:{
          bar:{
               etc:{}
          }
     }
}
```

I've tried with two loops but I can get it to work if there is three values in the array.

Comment: What do you want it to look like with three values in the array?

Comment: So show us what you have tried.

Comment: Will there always be two values? What should it look like if not?

Comment: Are you trying to convert into JSON by any chance?

Comment: not parsing json, updating what it should be if there is more values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var obj = {};
var pointer = obj;

array.forEach(function (item) {
    pointer = pointer[item] = {};
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h67ts/

---

If you have to support IE < 9, you can either use a regular loop, or use [this polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Compatibility):

```
if ( !Array.prototype.forEach ) {
  Array.prototype.forEach = function(fn, scope) {
    for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i) {
      fn.call(scope, this[i], i, this);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: IE says he does not like `forEach`.